# How can I allow multiple rows in a table the ability to toggle on or off with a materialize switch?

Tags: javascript, meteor, materialize

What I'm trying to accomplish is to allow multiple rows inside a table to toggle on or off without affecting the other rows in that same table. 
It works fine when I only have one row. But the moment I add another row , the switch starts turning off other rows.
Here's a video clip of what I mean->

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uLBrZND69Ps

And here's the code ->

```js
// ClIENT CODE
Template.orionMaterializeLayout.events({
 "change .switch input": function (event) {
  var change = event.target.checked;
  Meteor.call('toggleHidden', change);
 }
});
 
// SERVER CODE
Meteor.methods({
 'toggleHidden' : function(change){
  console.log(change);
     Banner.update({}, {$set:{hidden: change }});
 }
});
 
// COLLECTIONS CODE, WHAT RENDERS THE ON/OFF SWITCH ON THE TABLE
 
Banner = new orion.collection('slideshow', {
 
  title: 'Add Images', // The title of the page
  link: {
    title: 'Slideshow',
    section: 'top',
    image: '<i class="fa fa-picture-o"></i>'
  },
 
   tabular: {
    columns: [
      { data: 'hidden', title: 'Visibility', 
        render: function(doc){
          if (doc === true ){
            return '<div class="switch"><label>Off<input type="checkbox" checked="checked"><span class="lever"></span>On</label></div>'
          } else  {
            return '<div class="switch"><label>Off<input type="checkbox"><span class="lever"></span>On</label></div>'
          }
        }
 
      }
 
    ]
  }
});
```

Comment: If it's switching on and off rows you don't want, filter the rows by class or ids. Only switch on the rows with correct the class or id.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you intend the toggling to write the change to the database on the backend (Mongo collection on the server). However, your `Banner.update()` call does not specify which document to update - so it updates every document in your collection!

You need to do two things (with your code as-is). First, capture the data context that has triggered the event handler. Normally, that will be `this` within your handler. So `this._id` should return the document ID. Second, you need to pass that ID to your method, to ensure it only updates that document.

Without all of your code, it is hard to guarantee a correct answer (especially not knowing the data context within the template) but the below is likely to work:

```
// ClIENT CODE
Template.orionMaterializeLayout.events({
    "change .switch input": function (event) {
        var change = event.target.checked;
        Meteor.call('toggleHidden', change, this._id);
    }
});

// SERVER CODE
Meteor.methods({
    'toggleHidden' : function(change, docId){
        console.log(change);
        Banner.update({_id: docId}, {$set:{hidden: change }});
    }
});
```